# v-for method doesn't receive the right index

Tags: vuejs2

this is my code :

```
   <b-form @submit="onSubmit" @reset="onReset" >
    <b-card  v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.name">
          <input type="file" 
                 style="visibility:hidden;" 
                 id="file" 
                 ref="file" 
                 @click="printIndex(index)" @change.once="handleFileUpload($event.target,$event.target.files)"                           
/>
     {{index}}                   
    </b-card>
    </b-form>
```

my model :

```
items: [{
                    name: "soldat",
                    margin: 3,
                    labour: 2,
                    finition: 1,
                    demandMax: 40,
                    demandMin: 0
                },
                {
                    name: "train",
                    margin: 2,
                    labour: 1,
                    finition: 1,
                    demandMax: 800,
                    demandMin: 0
                }
            ]
```

printIndex() function only prints 0, while it should print 1 when I click on the second  displayed input object .
The {{index}} displays correctly 1 on the second object (train) .
It is like the INPUT can't access the INDEX variable, because it is a v-for .
Do you experiment the same behavior ?

With a modified vue code like this :

```
   <b-card  v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.index" @click="printIndex(index)">
          <input type="file" 
                 style="visibility:hidden;" 
                 id="file" 
                 ref="file" 
@change.once="handleFileUpload($event.target,$event.target.files)"
                 />                   
    </b-card>
```

printIndex() is triggered 2 times when clicking on INPUT , and also gives 0 the second time, while it should only display the index 1 when clicking on my second object, just like in angularJs.

I have no solution, I am bloqued. If anyone has a solution, i would really appreciate it .

This is the printIndex method :

```
printIndex(index){
          console.log(index)
        }
```

**EDIT : Excuse me, Some code was missing, added the @change  . I suspect that there is a conflict between both @change and @click.**

**EDIT 2 :**

```
 <input v-model="index" @click="printIndex(index)"></input>
```

is working perfectly inside the v-for loop, the error seems to be linked to  type="file" : this is the error  :

```
**File inputs are read only. Use a v-on:change listener instead.**
```

**EDIT 3 resolved, thank you**

I have placed the printIndex() function above the hidden button , in the label, like this :

```
 <label for="file" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"  @click="printIndex(index)">
                                  <i class="fas fa-user-astronaut"></i>
                                  <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Change picture</span>
                                </label>
                            
                                  <input
                                    type="file"
                                    style="visibility:hidden;"
                                    id="file"
                                    ref="file"
                                    @change="handleFileUpload($event.target,$event.target.files)"
                                    accept="image/*"
                                  />
```

The main problem was that an input type ="file" is **readonly**, so **you can't access his index** .

Comment: You mention `printIndex` all the time but don't include its code ?

Answer (score 1):

Your model objects doesn't have any `index` property so `:key="item.index"` is just wrong. Use `:key="index"` instead...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is true ! Unfortunatly ,I still experiment the same behavior after applying your code.

Comment: when clicking a button, printIndex(index) gets triggered 2 times . Maybe it is because of  @submit="onSubmit"

Comment: Changed my :key on the post .

Answer (score 0):

EDIT 3 resolved, thank you

I have placed the printIndex() function above the hidden button , in the label, like this :

```
 <label for="file" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block"  @click="printIndex(index)">
                                  <i class="fas fa-user-astronaut"></i>
                                  <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Change picture</span>
                                </label>
                            
                                  <input
                                    type="file"
                                    style="visibility:hidden;"
                                    id="file"
                                    ref="file"
                                    @change="handleFileUpload($event.target,$event.target.files)"
                                    accept="image/*"
                                  />
```

The main problem was that an input type ="file" is readonly, so you can't access his index .